# Get Index of each set of Duplicated Links

Tags: jquery

When a set of links like amazon.com or google.com (etc) exist on a page, it will be listed multiple times. I'm trying to find the index of each set of duplicated links.

This is what I'm expecting:

- eg. amazon.com (index 0)
- eg. amazon.com (index 1)
- eg. amazon.com (index 3)
- eg. google.com (index 0)
- eg. google.com (index 1)

However, I'm not getting the expected result with this function:

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $links = $("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']");
  var isDupe = $links.length > 1;
  if ($links.length > 1) {
    var rank = isDupe ? $links.not(this).index('a') : $(this).index('a');
    alert('\nLink Rank ' + rank + '\n\nYes, this is duplicate link');
  } else {
    alert('No, this is NOT a duplicate link');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> (Google is not a duplicate)
<BR>
<a href="http://www.intranet.com">Intranet</a> (Intranet is not duplicate)
<BR>
<BR>i want this to say index <strong>0</strong>, but it returns index 3
<BR>
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a> (Example is a duplicate)
<BR>
<BR>i want this to say index <strong>1</strong>, but it returns index 2
<BR>
<a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a> (Example is a duplicate)
<BR>
<BR>i want this to say index <strong>0</strong>, but it returns index 5
<BR>
<a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a> (Amazon is a duplicate)
<BR>
<BR>i want this to say index <strong>1</strong>, but it returns index 4
<BR>
<a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a> (Amazon is a duplicate)
<BR>
<BR>i want this to say index <strong>2</strong>, but it returns index 4
<BR>
<a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a> (Amazon is a duplicate)
<BR>
```

Comment: In first place, why do you render duplicate links?

Comment: I don't understand your expected results. Where do you expect the index to start from?

Comment: Why do you test `isDupe` inside the `if` block? It's the same as the expression you tested with `if`, so it can never be false.

Comment: we have situations when a link that goes to Request Info is at the top of the page and then we'll have link that goes to Request Info at the bottom of the page. The link is exactly the same, and I'm trying to identify the index so I can send that index value to our analytical package. The purpose is to try to make something that is not unique to be unique by identifying its rank location among its counter duplicated links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/no4gkk0n/18/)

In `var index = isDupe ? $links.not(this).index('a') : $(this).index('a');` change:

```
$links.not(this).index('a')
```

To:

```
$links.index(this)
```

Not sure if you need the `$(this).index('a')` part but if you do, it should be:

```
$('a').index(this)
```